# Take a specific part of a matrix imported from a .xls

Tags: matrix, import, excel

i would like to know if there are any ways to link headings of a table i had imported with the data in the table itself.
I imported a matrix from an excel file and i want to take a specific part of it. For example if in my table one row heads with "Italy" i want to know a procedure to extract in mathematica the content of the row (or the column or both of them) just writing (in mathematic) the name of the row (or the column)

Thanks! (sorry if i'had not explained it too much clearly)

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume your excel sheet has three columns with headings `Oct` through `Dez`.

Import it

```
imp = Catenate @ Import["excel.xlsx"]
```

> {{"Okt", "Nov", "Dez"}, {10., 11., 12.}, {1., 2., 3.}}

The `Catenate` is necessary to remove the outermost brackets.

Get header

```
head = imp[[1]]
```

> {"Okt", "Nov", "Dez"}

Get values

```
vals = imp[[2 ;;]]
```

> {{10., 11., 12.}, {1., 2., 3.}}

`[[]]` is a short form for `Part` and `2;;` means: from the 2nd position until the end

Build an `Association`

```
data = Association@Thread[Rule[head, Transpose@vals]]
```

> <|"Okt" -> {10., 1.}, "Nov" -> {11., 2.}, "Dez" -> {12., 3.}|>

You can now directly refer to your column names:

```
data["Nov"]
```

> {11., 2.}

Comment: Thank you. Now i have to try it because i'm working with excel files with thousend of rows and columns. My real problem was to create an association with the heading of the row (for example) and the content of the row itself. So, when in mathematica i digit the name of the headings's row i can recall the row i need, like i sad if my row calls "Italy" (after i imported the file in mathematica), i digit "Italy" and i can get the informations, all the data in the row..e so..

Comment: If your headings are the first items of the rows you would import with `Transpose @ Catenate @ Import["excel.xlsx"]`. The rest of my answer doesn't change.

Comment: the table i'm trying to import is an Input-Output table which has the headings i will associate with dataset in the first and second row , and in the first and second column

Comment: Could you show a small example of your data? Do you really need four different indexes?

Comment: [!file:///C:/Users/Andrea/Pictures/Immagine.png] sorry.i'm new in this forum ..I'm trying to understand how to put images...i don't know if it works..however it's necessary four different indexes because this is how this kind of table works

Comment: My excel file is: A1,B1,A2,B2 (empty)--C1,D1("EE")--A3,A4("EE")--C2,B3("Agricolture")--B4,D5("Forestery")--C3,D3,C4,D4(0.345;0.456;0.23;0.567).........these are the first 4 rows and 4 columns

Comment: Two questions. First question: Do the row and column headings always correspond? If there is `EE Agricolture` in `C1:C2` will there always be  `EE Agricolture` in `B3:B4` ? Second question: Is `EE` a constant? Or is there also something like `AB Agricolture` ?

Comment: No, "EE" is just another headings (it's an abbreviation for Europe)..about the first question if EE Agricolture is in C1:C2 , EE Agricolture will be always in A3:B3

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are looking for the [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) format. Using `"ExampleData/elements.xls"` to get an example .xls file:

```
ds = SemanticImport["ExampleData/elements.xls"]
```

[image]

Now

```
ds[1]
```

[image]

and

```
ds[All, "Name"]
```

[image]

Comment: For this specific example using `SemanticImport["ExampleData/elements.xls", {Integer, String, String,  Real}]` would result in a better formated Dataset.